Helix toolkit Wpf DX, how to load and transform an array of objs?
I have a wpf application, and I am spawning a dynamic point cloud using:
xaml:
  <hx:PointGeometryModel3D 
                Geometry="{Binding Points}"
                Transform="{Binding Points1Transform}"
                IsRendering="True"
                FixedSize="True"
                Size="5.5, 5.5" 
                Color="#00FF1B"  />

Code behind:
public PointGeometry3D _Points;

        public PointGeometry3D Points
        {
            get { return _Points; }
            set
            {
                if (_Points != value)
                {
                    _Points = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(null);
                }
            }
        }
        public Transform3D Points1Transform { get; set; }

Points1Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(0, 0, 0);
Points = new PointGeometry3D { IsDynamic = true, Positions = new Vector3Collection() };
        

and updating the positions on a timer with:
 public void ProcessingEventHandlerMap(object sender, DllFunctions.DenseTrackingFunctions.ProcessingEventArgsMap args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_Data.GotData == true)
                {

                    Points.ClearAllGeometryData();
                    Points.ClearOctree();
                    Points.Positions.Clear();


                    for (int j = 0; j < _Dense._processingArgsMap.pointData.Count(); j++)
                    {

                        Points.Positions.Add(new Vector3((float)_Dense._processingArgsMap.pointData[j].position[0] * 10, (float)_Dense._processingArgsMap.pointData[j].position[1] * 10, (float)_Dense._processingArgsMap.pointData[j].position[2] * 10));
                        Points.UpdateVertices();

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // I broke
            }

        }

This works perfectly, and I now need to replicate it with an obj file, loaded from disk. I have the file loaded as:
HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.MeshGeometry3D 
But how can I spawn an array and dynamically change the transforms?

What have you tried so far in terms of importing those points from the obj file? Are you able to actually distill that file into a collection of vectors? I think I need a little more information to be able to help.
